# WampServer virtual host redirects to localhost after installing SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, wamp, virtualhost

I followed these instructions [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lDRdewhH_vg) and was able to successfully get https://localhost to work on my WampServer local dev environment. However, ***the virtual host for the website in question redirects back to localhost*** instead of the site.

There are no errors, we just keep going round and round (not sure the technical term for that)

- Chrome
- Windows 10
- Latest WampServer
- PHP 8

I don't know what other metrics or data you might need, just let me know.

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lDRdewhH_vg